# Can I use Cygwin as a replacement for Ubuntu, for bash script testing?

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

Next wednesday i'm having an exam on Operating Systems. In this exam there will also be a part bash-scripting. The teacher itself will test the scripts in a Virtual Machine running Ubuntu.

Myself, however, I'm having serious troubles with running the latest Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) on a Virtual Machine (there are troubles with gnome running very slow). So I'm thinking about using Cygwin, which is doing the job great for another course.

The teacher already confirmed I can use that, but I'm thinking he doesn't know it at all. I've already tested the scripts we made in class and they're all running without errors. But I'm quite sure there are some things I have to mind on.

My question: would you use Cygwin as a replacement for the Ubuntu VM? Or should I stick it with the VM (maybe by using a different config/platform).

Comment: It depends on what you're going to do. In cygwin, some external programs might be missing (e.g. I don't have `top`, `pgrep`, `pstree` on mine at work), but most things should just work.

Comment: If you're having UI issues, maybe go for a Ubuntu Distro with a much lighter-weight UI. [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) and [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) are both Ubuntu distros with lighter-weight GUIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you configure networking and SSH properly on the Ubuntu VM you don't need to access the desktop.
Just connect using PuTTy from windows to ubuntu.

Btw, i use both linux and cygwin daily and there could always be issues. I wouldn't trust 100% compatibility unless someone has tested for the kind of scripts you are creating.